# Burning CD or DVD always fails at 100%. Error 15. Input output error

Tags: iso, dvd, burning

I am using an external drive over USB.

Burning Data-DVD/CD or burning an ISO-file on a DVD/CD is in process untill 100%. Then the tray is opened. The dialogue says, that the tray could not be opened. The only option is to press "cancel". This results in error 15. The actually written DVD/CD is not readable and useless.

The same error occurs when I try burning with k3b or with the following terminal command::

```
growisofs -dvd-compat -Z
```

This is the end of my log-file in brasero:

```
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Async SYNCHRONIZE CACHE succeeded after 0.1 seconds
BraseroLibburn Closing
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_dangerous
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Closing track 01  (absolute track and session number 1)
BraseroLibburn Something went wrong
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_error
BraseroLibburn finished with an error
BraseroLibburn asked to stop because of an error
error       = 15
message = "Ein Fehler trat beim Beschreiben der CD/DVD auf"
BraseroLibburn stopping
Session error : Ein Fehler trat beim Beschreiben der CD/DVD auf      
(brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2856)
```

Comment: which back-end was used? [cdrkit](http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/cdrecord.html) or [cdrtools](https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/ubuntu/cdrtools)?

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of libburn and I am quite puzzled by the log.
Obviously the SCSI operation of closing track and session failed.
But there is no message about the SCSI error condition.

I am unfamiliar with what Brasero is doing, but I'd expect that
it would not hide such a message from libburn. So i have to expect
that there was no message.

The only error pattern known to me, which would match, is a rare
problem between Linux kernels and USB 3. It can show up with a
wide variety of symptoms and seems to be related to USB 3 features
about timeout and power supply.

If "Error 15" means Linux variable "errno", then 15 means "Block device
required", which would indicate that the burner device file
misfunctioned. This would match well the range of USB 3 symptoms.
Possibly you can find messages about this event in the system logs.

So if your drive is plugged into a USB 3 socket try to find 
a USB 2 socket on your machine and plug it there. Please report back
whether this helped.

Have a nice day :)

Thomas

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Unfortunately I am getting the same erro when I plug it in my USB 2.0-Port. I must add that I  only have one USB 2.0 port. I had to plug my DVD drive in to a usb hub, which was connected to my USB 2.0 port because it has a usb power cord for burning. This try resulted in the same error: The blank CD is definitely burned untill 100%. Then the tray is opened, then I get the dialogue that the tray could not be opened.

Comment: Hard to say what's going on. It could be a problem with brasero or with the Linux kernel. Can you try other burn programs like Xfburn or K3B ? Please tell the exact growisofs command which fails.

Answer (score -1):

Clean the DVD Writer lens and then Try to Download cdbxp by typing

" sudo apt-get install cdbxp "

use that software to burn

Comment: As far I know, cdbxp is a burning software for Windows and there is no linux-port of this software in the official sources. Under Windows I always use cdbxp!

Comment: I should add that my DVD-RW-drive is built in an external USB-tray (manufactured by FIRSTCOM). I even tried another IDE-Drive, what resulted only in the same error.